# Flagging statistics, aka "Am I a bad person?"

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history, review-suspension

I recently received my second review ban for failing a triage audit by not flagging something as spam.  The audit was fine, I simply failed it because I had recently had a flag declined and was gun shy (the declined flag was also accurate).

That got me thinking, about my declined/disputed flag total and how it measures up to the general review population.  **Is it possible to query this data?**

What ratio of declines to reviews would change my D&D alignment or cause the moderators to summarily review-ban me on sight?

Edit:  To clarify, my question is whether it is possible to query flagging data either for my account or in aggregate across SO.  I do not need help on flagging; the last question is an invitation for creative responses.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule. It depends on *how badly you screw up*. If you keep approving outright spam and vandalism, over and over again even after automatic bans, we'll have a serious word with you. If you bumble through and get borderline things wrong a lot, we'll probably let you figure things out on your own.

Comment: If you are having trouble with flags, you might consider looking through relevant meta posts and figure out what you're doing wrong. That seems to be the underlying issue here and the reason for this post. It's nothing to be ashamed of; the use of flags can seem a little murky. I know I had trouble but, thanks to some great meta posts and discussion, I was able to get a better handle on them (I think)

Comment: If after doing some research like @codeMagic suggests you still have questions, feel free to write a new meta question.  Just be sure to include what you already know and what you need clarification on.

Comment: @Eric, there are several parts in your question that have a "?" after them, and it looks like the commenters were addressing the second one. Since that occurred before you added emphasis on the first one, it's understandable I believe.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - You are correct, and I have deleted my comment as non-constructive.  Thank you for the reality check.

Comment: Kinda related:  [rene's userscript for determining community consensus on reviews](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508) (this does not compare your flag accuracy only review history).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as flagging statistics, you can go to the Activity tab in your profile and click on the "xx helpful flags" link under the Impact section. For your account, that will take you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2587452). From there, you can see detailed statistics on the flags you have filed and their acceptance rate.

Looking at those numbers, I wouldn't worry too much about a single declined flag here and there. For the most part, your flagging has been accurate and it'd take a number of declined flags to even see a warning about this. Moderators can't directly ban you from flagging, only the system can if we decline enough of these in a short duration.

The only recent declined flag I see in there was one on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745339/why-is-the-swift-language-named-this-way) where you used a custom flag to state

> Resolveable via a trivial google search.

You don't need to use a custom flag for something like that, just use a standard close vote or close flag and the community will handle the rest. In fact, the question was already closed by the time the moderator saw that flag, so they had declined it with the stock reason

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Again, beyond that I wouldn't worry about your recent flagging history as you've been on the mark with the rest of them.

If you're really concerned about using a spam flag on something you suspect to be spam, but aren't sure about, use a custom flag and explain your suspicions. That could provide the context we need to see what you did.

Comment: For concerns about possible spam posts feel free to drop in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where we get the Stack Overflow spam reports from the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and are able to quickly asses such posts and help with extra flags if needed.